# Optional for finding if list contains object at index

Tags: java, option-type

I am exploring the use of Optionals.
Below I have a case where I would like to instantiate a new object (here Data object) if a list (containing Data Objects) doesn't have an object at a specific index.
Is this possible to achieve with Optional?

```
List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size();i++) {
    Data data = Optional.ofNullable(dataList.get(i)).orElse(new Data()); // this will throw an error of index out of bounds
}
```

Comment: You mention "specific index" but iterate over the entire list. Do you mean to get exactly _one_ element or replace all nulls with new instances?

Comment: As for the exception: if that's your actual code, i.e. no further manipulation of `i` or the list (e.g. by another thread), it can't throw that `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - the body should _never_ be executed with a negative `i` or a value that's out of bounds since the maximum allowed value of `i` would be `dataList.size() - 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) and more specifically  `Optional.ofNullable()` are not designed to catch any exception triggered in the expression execution passed to their factory methods. They expect a returned reference, `null` or not for `ofNullable().`

`Optional` was originally designed to convey/constraint that a method may return an thing or not (empty).
In some cases we could also rely on `Optional` to perform elegantly some `null` checks.

Here you are not in any of these cases since you want to check the size of the list before returning the element of the list or a new object.
So, a conditional statement and more particularly a ternary operator looks more adapted :

```
Data data = i < dataList.size() ? dataList.get(i) : new Data();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with your code. Works perfectly fine for me. `get(i)` can never throw AIOBE in your code since it is guarded by `size()`.

```
List<Integer> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
dataList.add(1);
dataList.add(null);
for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
  Integer data = Optional.ofNullable(dataList.get(i)).orElse(new Integer(-1));
  System.out.println(data);
}
```

Output is 1 and -1.